# Create Template for complex object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have an object like this

```
public class Locs
{
    public string City {get; set; }
    public int Zip {get; set; }
}

public class Names
{
    public string FirstName {get; set; }
    public string LastName {get; set; }
    public Locs[] Locations {get; set; }
}
```

For the class Names I am generating strongly typed View based on [Create Template]. But when its generated it only show input controls for FristName and Last Name. How can I create a View that can also get Locations from the html page? So that I can easily save data from submit button.

My Form is like this

```
<input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" />
<input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" />
<p>
    <input type="text" id="City1" name="City1" />
    <input type="text" id="Zip1" name="Zip1" />
</p>
<a href="#" onclick="a function which will add more <p> containing inputs">Add more locations</a>
```

As you can see User can dynamically create City and Zip. I am now sure how many he will create. How can I get such object in my view? Can i get such object automatically? Also I want to apply validations.

Comment: Can you be more clear on what you are trying to accomplish? I assume you want to render a form, but are you passing data with your object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to show an editor an for each locations, you can loop through the Locations property in your view:

Rest of your view...

```
<% for (int i = 0; i < Model.Locations.Count; i++)
{ %>
<%= Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Locations[i].City) %>
<%= Html.TextboxFor(model => model.Locations[i].Zip) %>
}%>
```

Continue your view.